# Rotating image by Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am testing image rotating by `jquery`. Reference is [here](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples) (Example 5).
What is it missing in my code, image does not rotate when I click?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rotate Image</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryRotate.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#image").rotate({ 
                   bind: 
                     { 
                        click: function(){
                            $(this).rotate({ angle:0,animateTo:180,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo })
                        }
                     } 

                });
            });
        </script>   
        <img src="images/aaa1.jpg" id="image"/> 
    </body>
</html>
```

package :

[image]

Comment: you have to include jQuery before the rotate library is included

Comment: your code is perfect check http://jsfiddle.net/RwEme/6926/

Comment: @rajeshkakawat, I test in IE and Firefox. it does not work. Thz for your supporting. I did not use `script url`. I download `js` file and put into my directory. Is it ok? I think, it will be ok.

Comment: Rajesh's example is working.  Did you click on the image?

Comment: @CycDemo did you click on image ??????

Comment: @CycDemo it doesn't  matter you are using local js file or script url,what matter is code which you have wrote and it is working perfectly, check your local jquery version

Comment: Sure, I click on image.

Comment: @CycDemo check the update below

Comment: @rajeshkakawat, version is `jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.1`

Comment: why don't just try with script url???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to include jQuery core

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryRotate.js"></script>
```

Also the closing tags for the script tag should be `</script>`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rotate Image</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryRotate.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#image").rotate({ 
                   bind: 
                     { 
                        click: function(){
                            $(this).rotate({ angle:0,animateTo:180,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo })
                        }
                     } 

                });
            });
        </script>   
        <img src="http://placehold.it/64" id="image"/> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I download and update my code. It does not work. Plz, check my update my post

Comment: Your updated post is work. Thanks. I am surprise, close tag `/>` and `</script>` are different.